# AWS CLI export volume information to CSV with instance name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

From Windows 10 AWS CLI, I've been able to successfully export EBS volume information to a .csv with the following command:

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes –-query "Volumes[*].[Attachments[0].VolumeId,AvailabilityZone,Attachments[0].InstanceId,Attachments[0].State,Size]" --output text > volumes.csv
```

I would like to know how to make two modifications: changing the instance ID to the instance name, and adding sortable columns to the .csv.

I've tried using 'InstanceName' and 'Name' in place of InstanceId but these seem to be invalid, as the CLI returns 'None' in this column when I know the instances do have names.

As far as adding columns automatically, no clue here

Edit: Also interested in adding whether the volume is encrypted or not to the query...I could not find this in AWSCLI docs.

Comment: You cannot get the instance name info from the describe-volumes api. You will need to call describe-instances using the instance_id you get from the response.

Comment: Thanks! Giving it a try in the AM and I'll update the post.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using steampipe for such queries involving multiple AWS resources.
https://steampipe.io/

Here is an example:

```
$ steampipe query --header --output csv "select vol.volume_id, vol.availability_zone, vol.attachments -> 0 -> 'InstanceId' as instance_id, ec2.tags -> 'Name' as instance_name from aws_ebs_volume as vol, aws_ec2_instance as ec2 where vol.attachments -> 0 ->> 'InstanceId' = ec2.instance_id" | head -n 3
volume_id,availability_zone,instance_id,instance_name
vol-0ffd49df0fbf51143,us-east-1d,"""i-0b69388137e6bd8d6”””,”””foo"""
vol-088dfa528f0c8748b,us-east-1d,"""i-0a2450d3220ea359d”””,”””bar”””
$
```